# packaging common python namespaces

Tags: python, namespaces, packaging, pypi

I'm looking to package and upload a library I have to PyPI in the next few days, but I'm a little unsure about my approach to the namespace.

I have a few otherwise unrelated projects with a similar approach and wanted to give them all the same namespace. For example:

- Library 1 namespace:  `abc.seo`
- Library 2 namespace:  `abc.ajax`
- Library 3 namespace:  `abc.ecommerce`
- etc

The problem is that I'm not sure if it's possible for two separate packages (eg eggs) to co-exist with the same parent namespace. Is this approach problematic, or is there a way around it? What's the best approach?

The libraries should not be packaged together, they are too unrelated. I would like to get it right before uploading so as to avoid painful namespace changes after making an "official" release.

<sup>(NB `abc` is not the real name, I wanted my question to be free from advertising)</sup>

**UPDATE**

I went with the following, to be nice to the people without setuptools installed:

```
try:
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    __path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

With the following in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    namespace_packages = ['rollyourown'],
    ...
```

Comment: Have you looked at the various eGenix `mx` packages on PyPi?   Look at those for examples.  Then you can ask more *specific* questions based on that pattern.

Comment: So you mean to say it's not problematic for a user to install two separate packages with the same parent namespace? This will never cause any issues? The `mx` packages appear to have a very complicated installation process, I'll try my best to see if they have any special workarounds for namespace issues.

Comment: Your "update" is in fact an answer, rather than an update of your question. I'd move it to be an answer, so we can vote on it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In each project base directory, create the following structure:

```
/setup.py
/abc/__init__.py
/abc/seo/
```

`/abc/__init__.py` contains :

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

`setup.py` contains :

```
setup(...,
    packages: ['abc', 'abc.seo'],
    namespace_packages = ['abc']
    ...
)
```

Reference documentation: [namespace packages](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#namespace-package-support).

Comment: Wonderful! This sounds like it solves the technical problem completely. Thanks!