# What does `__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)` do?

Tags: python, module, namespaces, runtime

In some `__init__.py` files of modules I saw such single line:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

What does it do and why people use it? Suppose it's related to dynamic importing and creating namespace at runtime.

Comment: You might find this question and answer helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064951/packaging-common-python-namespaces

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It boils down to two things:

1. `__import__` is a Python function that will import a package using a string as the name of the package.  It returns a new object that represents the imported package.  So `foo = __import__('bar')` will import a package named `bar` and store a reference to its objects in a local object variable `foo`.
2. From setup utils [pkg_resources'](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#namespace-package-support) documentation, `declare_namespace()` "Declare[s] that the dotted package name *name* is a "namespace package" whose contained packages and modules may be spread across multiple distributions."

So `__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)` will import the 'pkg_resources' package into a temporary and call the `declare_namespace` function stored in that temporary (the `__import__` function is likely used rather than the `import` statement so that there is no extra symbol left over named `pkg_resources`). If this code were in `my_namespace/__init__.py`, then `__name__` is `my_namespace` and this module will be included in the `my_namespace` namespace package.

See the [setup tools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#namespace-package-support) documentation for more details

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python) for discussion on the older mechanism for achieving the same effect.

See [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) for the standardized mechanism that provides similar functionality beginning with Python 3.3.

Comment: __import__ is a Python function, not a statement.

Comment: What? No! That's not what `declare_namespace` does at all. It doesn't just dump the contents of the `pkg_resources` module into the chosen namespace; `pkg_resources` is just the module where `declare_namespace` comes from. A package `foo` would use `pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)` to allow its implementation to be split into multiple `foo` folders. Pulling the contents of `pkg_resources` itself into your namespace would be entirely counterproductive.

Comment: @user2357112 not sure what I was getting at ~5 years ago. I updated the response accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

This is a way to declare the so called "namespace packages" in Python.

What are these and what is the problem:

Imagine you distribute a software product which has a lot of functionality, and not all people want all of it, so you split it into pieces and ship as optional plugins.

You want people to be able to do

```
import your_project.plugins.plugin1
import your_project.plugins.plugin2
...
```

Which is fine if your directory structure is exactly as above, namely

```
your_project/
    __init__.py
    plugins/
        __init__.py
        plugin1.py
        plugin2.py
```

But what if you ship those two plugins as separate python packages so they are located in two different directories? **Then** you might want to put `__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)` in each package's `__init__.py` so that Python knows those packages are part of a bigger "namespace package", in our case it's `your_project.plugins`.

Please refer to the [documentation](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages) for more info.