# How to organize my packages under some root package in PyPi?

Tags: python, pip, distutils

I have few packages which are more or less independent (see apack and bpack below). I would like to have them all available like this:

```
import mycompany.apack.somemodule
import mycompany.bpack.somemodule
```

Since they are independent I have separate setup.py for each of them to deploy them to PyPi and therefore different release cycle.

Here's a question: **Is it possible to have subpackages of root package with separated release procedure (each subpackage has it's own setup.py)? How to achieve that?**

Here's what I tried, but wasn't able to get it working.
My current setup.py looks like that:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name='mycompany-apack',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['mycompany.apack'],
    license='GPLv3')
```

These setup.py are creating following structure in dist-packages folder:

```
mycompany
  apack
    __init__.py
    somemodule.py
  bpack
    __init__.py
    somemodule.py
```

Now since my mycompany does not have __ init __.py (this is my guess) I'm getting following error:

```
>>> import mycompany.apack.somemodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mycompany.apack.somemodule
```

Comment: And here's very similiar question if not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064951/packaging-common-python-namespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Use `pkg_resources.declare_namespace` from the `setuptools` project.

## Long answer

You could use setuptools instead of distutils. It supports dependency management and namespaces,

For apack the project structure will look like this:

```
/apack/
 |- mycompany/
 |   |- __init__.py (1)
 |   `- apack/
 |       |- __init__.py
 |       `- submodule.py
 `- setup.py
```

For apack your `setup.py` will look like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='apack',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages())
```

The `__init__.py` marked as (1) will look like this:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
```

bpack will look very similar, except with `apack` replaced with `bpack`.

Let's assume there is also a cpack, which depends on apack and bpack.

It will look similar, but the `setup.py` will look like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='cpack',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['apack', 'bpack'])
```

If cpack is installed, apack and bpack will be installed as well.
Because of the namespace declaration, no conflicts occur

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source virtualenv/bin/activate
$ pip install cpack
$ python
>>> from mycompany.apack import submodule
>>> from mycompany.bpack import submodule
>>> from mycompany.cpack import submodule
```

Comment: I tried this way. If I install both apack and bpack and then remove apack the bpack becomes non importable. This is happening because removal of apack leading to removal pack/__ init __.py And this is exactly the same problem I have with distutils if I start installing root pack from both apack and bpack there. So far setuptools and distutils are the same...

Comment: The key point which is missing in the answer is use of namespace_packages in setup call. Only it will make a "namespace" from root package pack